# android won't inflate my fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following MainActivity.java

```
import java.util.Date;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mydomain.myappname.CardoApplication;
import com.mydomain.myappname.R;
import com.mydomain.myappname.adapters.HomeTabsPagerAdapter;
import com.mydomain.myappname.extensions.SlidingTabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private HomeTabsPagerAdapter mPageAdapter;

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setViewsClassMembers();

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mPageAdapter = new HomeTabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);
        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        mTabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        mTabs.setViewPager(mViewPager);      
    }


    private void setViewsClassMembers() {
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    }


}
```

Also have this ActiveFragment.java code

```
package com.xplete.cardo.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.mydomain.myappname.R;

public class ActiveFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_active, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

and this is my fragment_active.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_active"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="You Are In Tab active"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</fragment>
```

When I run it I get this error message:

> 10-25 13:49:09.014: E/AndroidRuntime(8699):
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
>   inflating class fragment

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did wrong in XML layout. `<fragment>...</fragment>`

change it to `Layout` like `<RelativeLayout> ...</RelativeLayout>`

### Corrected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_active"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="You Are In Tab active"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yep. Stupid mistke. Thank you very much!